# Abbreviating the thing one'll surely do

Tags: grammar, adverbs, abbreviations

When someone says as an example:

```
Ask me any questions you had.
```

I want to respond like this:

```
Will sure do.
```

Or

```
Sure will.
```

I've seen these two structures but it feels more correct to use an adverb like `surely` instead. How correct do these sound as non-adverbs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this US English speaker, **will do!** sounds idiomatic, and **sure will!** is good too, but *will sure do!* does not.

I don't know if there's a good grammatical *reason* for that; it is just that we say some of those things and do not say others.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. So, if I wanted to be as polite as possible, do you think `will do` can convey a bit of unwillingness; if so, what should I use instead? Also, if this gets used in an official exam like IELTS, will it be counted as a grammatical mistake because using an adverb seems like the right structure for me but probably is okay in daily conversations...

Comment: *Will do* actually sounds very willing!  But it is also very informal.  I would not use it on an official exam, but it is fine in conversation.